# Angular js - Laravel CORS preflight channel did not succeed

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, ionic-framework, cross-domain

I am trying to create mobile application in ionic framework, for that I have to use CROS with angular js application working on localhost:8100. The server side of this application is hosted and working under PHP framework Laravel. For cross-origin request I have set up following headers in Laravel filter.php

```
App::before(function($request){ 
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content- Type, Access-Control-Allow-Origin'); 
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS'); 
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true'); 
});
```

When I am trying to post some data on a url, getting an error reason CORS preflight channel did not succeed. My angular js script is given below.

```
var url = http://example.com/location
var postdata = {some : “data”};
$http.post(url, postdata)
   .success(function (data) {
      // Some success code
   })
   .error(function (data) {
      // Some failed code
   });
```

Answer (score 2):

Run a post request through postman and you should see a verifycrsf token error. You can get through this by editing the **verifycrsf.php** file in your Laravel file, add your paths to the function there and it should work.

Example: `'api/*' for example.com/api/matric`

Comment: I have filter.php, but where is **verifycrsf.php** located in laravel.

Comment: check your midleware dir

Comment: I am using Laravel 4.2, I think verifycrsf.php is not available there.